# Send the same message to several hosts (Broadcast in Ethernet LAN)

Tags: omnet++

I'm trying to understand how Omnet++ works since a couple of months and I'm facing a problem.

I'm working with the INET framework, more particullary with the Networks NED file (examples/ethernet/lans/networks.ned).

In a given simulation, I want to send the same packet at the same time, for all neighbouring hosts. But I don't have any idea of how can I do. I only know how to specify a unique destination address.

Does anyone have any idea ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: can you provide an example of *how you specify a unique destination address*?

Comment: In the INI file like this: **.hostC.cli.destAddress = "hostA"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two possible ways to achieve broadcast:

1. Broadcast functionality offered by the module you are using
2. Broadcast as given in the OMNeT++ manual

For the first one, if I assume that you are simulating a network, there is usually a broadcast IP in real networks. Maybe that is implemented in the module you are using. For example `255.255.255.255` might be the [broadcast IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address) for your network. You will have to know the IP address range of your LAN, and somehow infer the broadcast IP from there, by analysing the model.

The second option would be using the description for [broadcasting from the OMNeT++ user manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec168). Where a broadcast is hardcoded to the behaviour of the module/node, excluding the concept of IP etc.

Comment: There's no IP layer in the Switched Full Duplex Ethernet model (which I must use) given by INET framework. 

I'll try to hardcode the the broadcast functionnality in the EtherAppCli.cc file, according to the OMNET++ user manual. 

I'll keep you updated

Answer (score 1):

**My solution:**

It only needs to specify `**.hostA.cli.destAddress = "FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF"`.

I couldn't figure out what if the MAC broadcast address was configured in the model.

Thank you user4786271 for your help, you weren't so far from the solution.

Comment: obviously the solution was model specific, and since I have not used that model could not provide the exact solution. It seems to be closer to the option 1) I suggested

Comment: I have one subsidiary question : how to implement the so-called "multicast", which is different from the broadcast, since it consists in sending the packet to a group of hosts in the network ?

Comment: As in the previous question, you can first investigate if the model you are using offers such a functionality. If not, you can do it programmatically by creating a mapping between a given address (string), e.g.: `MU:LT:IC:AS:T0` and a given container (`std::list` or `std::vector`). You can make the nodes "subscribe" to this multicast address, and then use a for loop to do the sending for all the nodes that have inserted their name (subscribed) to the `MU:LT:IC:AS:T0` container.